# How to make a animation like Swipe

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, calayer

[image: 1.1]

[image: 1.2]

[image: 1.3]

[image: 1.4]

[image: 1.5]

How to make a swipe animation like shown in the images. I guess it uses CALayer but not sure.

[image]

Comment: maybe you should upload an animated gif so we can easily understand what you trying to do.

Comment: updated the question with gif image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the arrow image, you can use `UIImage` `animatedImage(with:duration:)`

[animatedImageWithDuration](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimage/1624149-animatedimage)

You can provide multiple images and a timespan and the image will animate

Comment: i guess this should be a solution. thanks let me do this and will get you know.

Comment: any luck Parv ?

Comment: it actually works, just need a little modification in images. thanks